# Filtering data in a CSV File with a Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am new to PowerShell.
I need to write a script that shows only the non-human E-Mail address out of a CSV file.

With that I mean that it only shows addresses like “Admin, news, support, fax” and not addresses like “Hans Mueller, Tim Cook, Paul Rot”.
Here is an example from the list: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LxvV.png)

So I need a function with that I can filter multiple keywords.

In the CVS file are E-Mail addresses, alias, Names.
The CVS file is exported out of the Exchange Admin Center.

I tryed this:

```
$csvdata = import-csv "C:\Users\benedikt.pracht\Desktop\CVS Vergleich\Export.csv" -Delimiter ","
$csvdata | Where-object {$_.Emailaddress -match "@domain1.local"}
foreach ($user in $csvdata){
if($user.name -match "admin"){$parsedusers += $user.name}
elseif($user.name -match "Administrator"){$Parsedusers += $user.name}
}
$parsedusers | Out-file "C:\Users\benedikt.pracht\Desktop\CVS Vergleich\parsedcsvdata.csv"
```

But it only gave out this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGOsa.png)

Comment: "Paul Rot" is a name, not an email address. Can you post a few sample lines from your CSV file?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have multiple rows, one of them are their names like “Paul Rot” I will update my post with examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this but here is an example

```
$csvdata = import-csv "C:\csvdata"
$csvdata |
 Where-object {$_.Emailaddress -match "@domain1.local"} |
 Export-csv "C:\parsedcsvdata" -NoTypeInformation
```

This will get all the email addresses that have your domain.
You can follow the same steps to filter even more.

```
$csvdata = import-csv "C:\csvdata"
$csvdata | Where-object {$_.Emailaddress -match "@domain1.local"}
foreach ($user in $csvdata){
if($user.name -match "anotherword"){$parsedusers += $user.name}
elseif($user.name -match "anotherword"){$Parsedusers += $user.name}
}
$parsedusers | Out-file "C:\parsedcsvdata.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that and comment again.

Comment: I think I did something wrong, there are only these two characters in it :"ÿþ"